# Scroll a page with 100% height fixed div which always on top and shouldn't cover the footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/9fCfE/1/

```
.fixed {
width: inherit;
height: 95%;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
position: fixed;
}
footer {
width: 100%;
}
```

Fixed div must be always on top and shouldn't cover the footer when I scroll.
100% height or from top to footer.

How can I do it?

Comment: https://delicious.com/discover - good example but without the footer.

Comment: How do you want\expect it to look when the user scrolls all the way to the bottom? The fixed red strip to go under the green footer? Or something else?

Comment: Fixed red strip decreases. height >100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cobbled together a quick and dirty implementation of what you asked using jQuery, `offset()`, `scrollTop()` and `height()`

Here's the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/EaugF/).

Is this what you wanted? If so - why? :)
I don't see any visual difference between this method, and the one where the fixed element goes under the footer.

Comment: But now fixed block doesn't scroll.

Comment: Now it's under the footer.

Comment: Nope, it is not :) See how the scrollbar ends [just where the footer starts](http://i.imgur.com/W5vrwDA.png?1)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to drop the z-index of the fixed region so that when it would otherwise cover the footer, it instead moves behind it.  You'll need to make sure the footer is `position: relative;`.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9fCfE/3/)

If, instead, you want the two to never intersect, you're in for a harder challenge.

The best way to do it would to be giving your fixed element a fixed height, giving your footer a fixed height, and making sure that the fixed element height + the footer height <= the screen height.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9fCfE/4/)

Those are really your only options - you essentially have to design around it.  To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to dynamically shrink the fixed element when it intersects with other elements on the page (ignoring the rest of the elements on the page is the *purpose* of `position: fixed`, after all).

Comment: Nope. The block shouldn't cover the footer or on/under footer. The block should change height when it covers footer.

Comment: @NickBolsh: Can you give an example of someplace where this is done?  Everywhere I've seen fixed elements they've designed around the problem of intersecting footers by making sure the heights were such that it couldn't happen.

Comment: @NickBolsh What's the (visual) difference between the block changing height and the block going under the footer? In both cases the user can't see the area of the fixed block of which the footer "takes place"

Comment: I couldn't find example. I want to see fixed div and footer on a page.

Comment: Something like this - http://store.apple.com/us/configure/MD094LL/A . But right side shouldn't go outside on top.

Comment: @NickBolsh In the example you specified the "fixed" doesn't change size at all... I don't see how this relates to what you asked